# How do I mount a USB floppy disk drive?

Tags: usb, mount

I have tried to mount my usb floppy disk drive in 11.04 Natty. So far I have managed to use the udisks --mount/dev/sdf command in terminal, but get a message that I have not stated a filetype

john@john-desktop:~$ udisks --mount /dev/sdf
Mount failed: Error mounting: mount: you must specify the filesystem type

This is the result I get when trying to mount the usb floppy disk drive. Anyone know how to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

`udisks` is asking you to specify the filesystem format because it cannot figure it out by itself. The reason it cannot is because you are telling it the wrong device to mount. You don't actually mount **disks**. You mount **partitions** (also called **volumes**). So instead of running

```
udisks --mount /dev/sdf
```

Run:

```
udisks --mount /dev/sdf1
```

That mounts the first partition on the disk (assuming the disk really is `/dev/sdf`). It's very rare for a floppy disk to have more than one partition. If it is not partitioned at all, then you can partition it with [`fdisk`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/en/man8/fdisk.8.html) and then format it with [`mkdosfs`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/en/man8/mkdosfs.8.html), both of which must be run as [`root`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_user) with [`sudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/en/man8/sudo.8.html) (or do both with [GParted](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/en/man8/gparted.8.html)), but if that is the case, make sure it's the right device, because if it's a different drive with important data on it, you could lose that data.

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting the part about **defining the format**. `udisks --mount /dev/sdf --mount-fstype=vfat` (or any other type).

Comment: Actually, the OP is forgetting to **identify which partition to mount**. It should be `/dev/sdf1` rather than `/dev/sdf`. `udisks` only tells you that you have to specify the filesystem type when it cannot infer it itself, and when that happens it is almost always because you are trying to mount the wrong kind of device (in this case, a disk rather than a partition/volume) or the volume is unformatted, formatted with an unrecognized (and likely unmountable) filesystem, or corrupt.

Comment: You might be able to force `udisks` to "succeed" with the `--mount-fstype` flag, but this would be **bad**, because you would be writing to the disk in a nonstandard and possibly unstable way. You'd likely lose what data you had on the disk, and whatever data you wrote to the disk afterwards would likely be inaccessible (possibly even when mounted in the same way, though this is a reasonable way to attempt to recover data written after this mistake is made).